# How to set foreign key ID in factory girl factory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, factory-bot, belongs-to

Here are my models:

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sections
end
```

In my `Loan` factory, I would like to automatically create an organization and set it for it. How can I accomplish this?

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :section do
    organization_id???
    title                 { Faker::Lorem.words(4).join(" ").titleize }
    subtitle              { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    overview              { Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(5).join("\n") }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to set up associations within factories. You need first to have a factory for your organization :

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :section do
    ...
  end
end
```

Then you can just call organization, FactoryGirl will take care on generating your organization

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :section do
    organization
    title                 { Faker::Lorem.words(4).join(" ").titleize }
    subtitle              { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    overview              { Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(5).join("\n") }
  end
end
```

if you want to know more you can go here : http://rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md